# How to get only few sub folders from a parent mapped local path : TFS command line

Tags: command-line, tfs, tfvc

I want to check-out only few folders their sub folders from a TFS project. i don't want to check out the whole projects. i know that using cloak command i can exclude certain files/folder from being checked out. But in my case the number of cloak path is much much greater than the number of paths needs to be check out.

Is it possible that i create a workspace and mapped it with a local folder and then getting items  by specifying only the server paths which i only needed.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a TFVC workspace you can easily map any folders that you like at any level.

Create a workspace and map it to the sub folder that you want to get. You don't need the whole project.

Even better, you don't need to "get" all of the files that are in scope of the workspace. When you configure it just say "no" to a full get. Then selectively get files or folders.